# Nextjs: Prevent a XML file in the public folder from being wrapped in HTML

Tags: xml, next.js, sitemap

I've created a `sitemap.xml` file and added it to the public folder of my Next.js project. However, when I access it and inspect the code I can see it's wrapped in HTML. For that same reason Google is not accepting the URL saying it should be in XML.

So the question is: How to ensure the file is shown in the same format (xml) instead of being wrapped in HTML?

Comment: "when I access it and inspect the code" — Are you inspecting the XML code or are you inspecting the DOM of the browser's rendering of the XML?

Comment: I'm inspecting the DOM. But the problem is that Google says the file is not XML